# How to insert value in single linked list after a certain value?

Tags: python, list, linked-list

This is my code snippet for doing the task in the title above:

```
def insert_Position(self, value, pos):
    new_node = Node(value)
    temp = self.head
    while temp.data == pos:
        temp = temp.next
    new_node.next = temp.next
    temp.next = new_node
```

I want to insert value `45` after the value `40` but I got the output like this

```
10 20 30 40 50

10 45 20 30 40 50
```

`pos` contains value after which I want to insert new value.

I want output like:

```
10 20 30 40 45 50
```

Comment: you need to manage the pointers so that they are in the desired order

Comment: Did you mean: `while temp.data != pos:`?

Comment: btw Can you update your question with the definition of `Node`?

Comment: thanks quamrana buddy i got the answer

Comment: btw don't correct your question otherwise the millions of future programmers who come after us won't be able to find this question.

Answer (score 0):

The while-loop condition is not correct.

```
def insert_Position(self, value, pos):
    new_node = Node(value)
    temp = self.head
    while temp <= pos:
        temp = temp.next
    new_node.next = temp.next
    temp.next = new_node
```